# ASP.Net checkbox to return a "Yes" or "No" value (instead of True / False)

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

I am using C# and ASP.Net 3.5, and trying to get a "Yes" / "No" value from checkbox, rather than a True / False. Is there an easy way or do I need to do "if" statements?

Comment: I am curious why you want to do this? Working with a boolean value is much easier than working with a string representing the same thing.

Comment: The value of the checkbox get displayed in a "Print This Page", and the client wants to see a "Yes / No" as opposed to a "True / False"

Comment: Clients like that "I-am-in-control" feeling

Comment: I assume you aren't persisting this data in any other place than the web page and thus you are rendering the "Print This Page" based on the control values instead of some other object that contains the data.

Comment: @DougStalter: Correct, this is a simple data retrieve from db, user makes modifications, prints out the page; No saving to database;

Comment: @Luiscencio:, I just do as I am told :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

sure try this:

```
string doesThisWork = chkBox.Checked ? "Yes":"No"
```

[more info...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks Luiscencio

Answer (score 5):

How about adding a extension method to the CheckBox class for this:

```
public static class CheckBoxExtensions
{
    public static string IsChecked(this CheckBox checkBox)
    {
        return checkBox.Checked ? "Yes" : "No";
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var checkBox = new CheckBox();
checkBox.Checked = true;

Console.WriteLine(checkBox.IsChecked());
// Outputs: Yes
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate the behaviour you want by using a ternary statement.

Something like

`string answer = checkbox.Checked ? "Yes" : "No";`

would do you perfectly.

If for some reason you want to get the actual Yes/No direct from the checkbox (and I can see no reason for this at all) then you could subclass the component and instead of true/false have it take strings. Seems a little silly to do that though as effectively the "yes"/"no" is a humanisation, for me also its less code to maintain to derive it this way and this is pretty standard.

Answer (score 1):

```
string YesNo = chkYesNo.Checked ? "Yes" : "No";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
checkbox.Checked ? "Yes" : "No"
```

If you want to be clever, you can use a dictionary:

```
static readonly Dictionary<bool, string> BooleanNames = new Dictionary<bool, string> { 
    { true,  "Yes" },
    { false, "No"  }
};

BooleanNames[checkbox.Checked]
```

However, you really shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using an asp.net checkbox control and looking at the 'Checked' property. If so, you need a statement to translate the boolean value to yes/No:

```
string yesNo = checkbox_control.Checked ? "Yes" : "No";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you a no if statement alternative (probably not the best approach in this case, but...):

```
Dictionary<Boolean, String> strings = new Dictionary<Boolean, String>();
strings.Add(true, "Yes");
strings.Add(false, "No");
```

Then when you need the value:

```
String yesNo = strings[checkbox.Checked];
```

Answer (score 0):

string doesThisWork = (bool)chkBox.Checked ? "Yes":"No"

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.