# How to define CheckBox in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql

I have a check box in my form that I need to define along with other fields for inserting data. But I am not sure How to define it for inserting data. Below is my code.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailTmp", (txtEmail.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneTmp", (txtPhone.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgreeTmp", (cbAgree.CheckBox));
```

Comment: Is this ASP, WPF, Winform, Silverlight, or what?

Comment: Are you asking how to put it into your ADO.NET command object as you've pasted, or asking how to define it on your form?  And if the latter, we need to know what Servy asked above.

Comment: "cbAgree.Checked" is your answer and if you want yes/no in return then have a look for it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435342/asp-net-checkbox-to-return-a-yes-or-no-value-instead-of-true-false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your pasted code, I think you want this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgreeTmp", (cbAgree.Checked));
```

or possibly something like:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgreeTmp", (cbAgree.Checked ? 1 : 0));
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining it clearly. I was a little confused. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgreeTmp", (cbAgree.Checked));
```

This will give you a boolean value of true if checked, false if not. SQL will translate this into a 0/1 if you have the field in the SQL db as a bit.

Edit: As a side note, you don't need the "@" in front of the AgreeTmp